# Prompt for username/password on login with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Is there a way in capistrano to have it prompt the user for both the username and the password to the site it's deploying to?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

Have you already uncommented this line from your `config/deploy.rb`?

```
# you might need to set this if you aren't seeing password prompts
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's not straight your question, I use a deploy.yml file in which I have the following variables:

```
website: 
git_user: 
passphrase: 
server_user: 
repository:
```

In the deploy.rb, I added:

```
require 'yaml'
CAP = YAML.load_file("./config/deploy.yml")
```

Then I use it this way:

```
set :scm_passphrase, CAP["passphrase"]
```

I didn't put the password of my server cause either I enter them when Capistrano requests it or my computer is in the white list of the server so the deployment is direct.